# Is the evolution & development of language better described by Deleuze concept of the rhizome than the traditional tree?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, deleuze, deleuze-and-guattari

Deleuze & Guattari introduce the idea of the *rhizome* in their text *A thousand Plateaus* as a metaphor closer to the reality than *aboroscent* (tree-like) descriptions can.

The question is how does one theorise rhizomatically? Given that Deleuze concepts form a closely linked set of ideas with *singularity, virtuality & multiplicity*, must all of these ideas be brought to in to *apply* the concept of a Rhizome?

Is the evolution of language a good example to theorise with - after all it is traditionally described by a tree? Can one, for example, suggest the existence of a tap-root was actually forced onto linguists by their chosen mode of description - a tree - whereas a rhizomatic description does away with a point-like origin.

We also have a picture of say the Indo-European language family starting of at some distant tap-root and slowly diversifying and splitting into many languages, with each branch then developing in perpetual isolation. In this picture, one cannot visualise creolisation where two languages at one time far apart is put into sudden contact and either one perishes, or a new hybrid (creole) develops.  Or two languages that were in close contact and actually mutually intelligible, by some force are closed off from each other, and so developing independently eventually become mutually unintelligible.

Can one say then that the Rhizome is arguably closer ontologically to the reality of language than the traditional linguists *image of thought/language* - the tree?

Has this formulation been used in the (non-Wittgenstein and/or non-analytical) philosophy of language/linguistics at all? If it has, by whom - and what has been the reception?

Comment: Linguistics.SE might be a more appropriate place for this.

Comment: Why? isn't that a bit like saying the philosophy of mathematics should belong to math.SE? I'm trying to understand Deleuzes idea of the Rhizome by putting into contact with something that is usually described in a tree-like fashion.

Comment: Is this philosophy of linguistics, or *theory* of linguistics? This question addresses how individual languages evolved (one might say speciated --- in which case the unsharpness of species becomes an informative observation); while this is an interesting topic, I'm not sure what makes it philosophical, unless to observe the scope and limitations of a theory is inherently philosophical. Is the observation "binary branchings are not always an adequate tool for modelling certain things" a deep observation any more?

Comment: Neither - *Rhizome* is a term in the Philosophy of Deleuze. I'm asking have I understood this term correctly by using it on a simple but also complex example. Does that not make it philosophical - or more exactly how to use philosophical terminology coined by a continental philosopher. (Its a bit like attempting to understand the idea of continuity by testing it out on a simple example like the real line). If you don't think that the question has much depth or that I have phrased it well - then that is a separate issue - and probably on balance I can agree with.

Comment: This question as it is currently formulated is off-topic because it concerns linguistics.

Comment: If the main thrust of the question is about Rhizomicism, perhaps you should refocus the question on that, and perhaps present the evolution of language (and some other examples) as candidate examples which you would like feedback on.

Comment: Regarding your edit: I don't see how the notion of abandoning "points" in mathematics relates to rhizomes. Is this meant generally to be a question of the spirit of overturning of earlier foundations to explore other formulations? Because it's not clear to me how to address this question, whether or not you try to cast it in terms of rhizomes.

Comment: yes, 'over-turning of foundations' - I thought that was obvious; are you suggesting that has to be made explicit as well? I've expanded on the ways that this question can be answered, if that helps.

Comment: I don't think you have to make that obvious: I'm trying to indicate that such a theme would be overly broad, and not have much to do with rhizomes in particular as a concept.

Comment: @deBeaudrap: well, I've asked the question at linguistics.SE as they have philosophy of language category there. Though I'll be majorly surprised if they've come across Deleuze...

Comment: Assuming that it actually is rhizomes rather than language which is the focus of your question (you seem to be asking about the evolution of language as an instance of rhizomic behaviour to see whether you understand rhizomes, rather than to see if you understand the evolution of language), it is appropriate here. The critique of my previous comment is that it's not obvious why other revaluations of foundations elsewhere, which are not in any clear way rhizomic, have anything to do with the subject; assuming your question is about rhizomes and not examples of revaluations of foundations.

Comment: Deleuze's philosophy is a fascinatingly 'preformed' world with no clear entry point. To understand the rhizome you have to know multiplicity, to get multiplicity you have to know what he means by singularity, to understand singularities as he conceives them you have to be acquainted with the virtual, and how it differs from Bergson's formulation, yet its impossible to see the virtual without getting its integrity to morphogenesis, which means you have to know differenTiation and differenCiation, which means you have to know difference in itself, as a function of repetition for itself .. etcetc

Comment: @DrSister: ok, I've understood that his system is hermetic. But presumably when Deleuze manfactures concepts they can be applied to things outside the his own system? Or is the idea of trying to understand language as Rhizomatic just wrong-headed? Or does this mean one can't apply his concepts in isolation but all together - that is one needs to see how virtuality, multiplicity & singularity apply to language too?

Comment: what do you suppose the rhizome is to Deleuze? are you sure you understand the term?

Comment: " how does one theorise rhizomatically" - 1000 plateaus is an attempt to do precisely just this ..

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest looking at *Postulates of Linguistics*, the fourth plateau I think, which deals with this in a little more depth. I wanted to draw together a few lines and thoughts here to maybe help bootstrap some further analysis.

Quickly: D+G's strategy involves deployment of mutually-exclusive dualisms or binarisms; in order to shatter or crystallize the hierarchical model-copy general system (of knowledge, power, etc.)

*Rhizome* asks a question about the speeds and movements that compose a book: what is the body without organs of a book? For a long time, they explain, we had an image of the book as nature, arborescent, vegetal. --But might there be other kinds of books...? :)

It strikes me as perhaps also interesting here that they characterize language as spreading like a patch of oil: a smooth space, expansive or even "superfluid"; like society, like desire, flowing and escaping...

Comment: There's clearly a lot more we could do around this, but I think it probably makes sense to do that work from the context of more specific/pointed questions.